# Method save does not exist in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Updated: Here is my controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->input('id');
    $success_output = '';
      $companies = companies::find($ids);
      companies::where('id',$ids);
      $this->validate($request,
        ['company_name' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);
      $companies->company_name = $request->input('company_name');
      $companies->status = $request->input('status');
      $companies->save();

      $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Inserted</div>';

      return redirect('/companies')->with('success','updated');
}
```

here is my index.balde.php:

```
$('#action1').click(function (){
               var Ids = new Array();
               var Names = new Array();
               var Status = new Array();
               if($(".selected").length){
                $(".selected").each(function(){
                  Ids.push($(this).children(".id").html());
                  Names.push($(this).children(".company_name").html());
                  Status.push($(this).children(".status").html());
                });
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'update',
                  method:'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data:{
                    "id":Ids,
                    "company_name":Names,
                    "status":Status
                  },
                  // "id":Ids,
                  // "company_name":Names,
                  // "status":Status,
                  success: function(data){
                    $('#form1').html(data.success);
                  },
                  error: function(data)
                  {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#form1').html(data.success);
                  }
                  });
                alert(Ids);
                alert(Names);
                alert(Status);

               }else{
                alert("No row is selected.");
               }
            });
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::post('update','AjaxController@update');
```

where is the problem? in console it returns that the "method save does not exist." couldn't find a solution. and also I'm a beginner. and this is for update multiple row in a single time.

Comment: Frist, you need to check the ID from your post request. for example if($request->input('id')) { echo $request->input('id')} else { echo "id is required!"}

Comment: Can you post your ´companies´ model? What is the route to your ´update´ function? If you model is right, all is needed ´$companies = new companies($request->all());´ followed by the validation and `$companies->save();`

Comment: Do a `dd()` on `$companies`; see what type of object it is. It it's `null`, a `Collection` or a `Builder`, `save()` is not available. If it's a `companies` (note, use Studly Caps and Singular for Model, so `Company`) Model, then you can save.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey , I have updated by question, and provide the three files including route